Python, Selenium Web Scraping: Popup Issue from the First Web Page to the Second Web Page
enter code hereThis issue has been bothering me for several days, and I have not been able to find a suitable solution. Currently, I am using Python and Selenium for web scraping. After clicking a button on the first website, it forces the opening of a second website, which triggers an alert popup. However, despite trying many methods, I have been unable to capture the alert popup to proceed with the subsequent automated operations. If I use keyboard.press(Key.enter), other operations may interfere. I would like to know if anyone has encountered a similar situation and can provide a solution. This is the point where the process stops each time to check or look for the alert window. The simulated situation of the website is as shown in the HTML below , and python. Thank you very much.
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="zh-TW">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>upload picture</title>
</head>
<body>
    <button id="openWindow">Open new window</button>
    <div>
        <h3>Uploaded images will appear below:</h3>
        <img id="uploadedImage1" src="" alt="uploadedImage1" style="max-width: 500px;">
        <img id="uploadedImage2" src="" alt="uploadedImage2" style="max-width: 500px;">
    </div>
    <script>
        let uploadCount = 0;

        document.getElementById('openWindow').onclick = function() {
            const newWindow = window.open('upload.html', 'Upload Image', 'width=500,height=500');
            newWindow.focus();
        };

        window.addEventListener('message', function(event) {
            if (event.origin !== window.location.origin) {
                alert('Data from unknown sources!');
                return;
            }
            uploadCount++;
            const imageURL = event.data;
            if (uploadCount === 1) {
                document.getElementById('uploadedImage1').src = imageURL;
            } else if (uploadCount === 2) {
                document.getElementById('uploadedImage2').src = imageURL;
            }
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="zh-TW">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>upload picture2</title>
<script>
    window.onload = function() {
        alert('Please select a picture and upload it!');
    };
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <input type="file" id="fileInput">
    <button id="uploadButton">upload</button>
    <script>
        document.getElementById('uploadButton').onclick = function() {
            const fileInput = document.getElementById('fileInput');
            if (fileInput.files.length === 0) {
                alert('Please select a profile!');
                return;
            }
            const file = fileInput.files[0];
            const reader = new FileReader();
            reader.onload = function(e) {
                window.opener.postMessage(e.target.result, window.opener.location.origin);
                window.close();
            };
            reader.readAsDataURL(file);
        };
    </script>
</body>
</html>


from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import time



service = Service('/usr/local/bin/chromedriver')
options = Options()
options.add_experimental_option('detach', True)


driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=service, options=options)


driver.get('http://127.0.0.1:5500/index.html')


open_window_button = driver.find_element(By.ID, 'openWindow')
open_window_button.click()

time.sleep(2)
print('sleep is over.')
# This is the point where the process stops each time to check or look for the alert window.


file_input = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.ID, 'fileInput')))
file_path = ''  
file_input.send_keys(file_path)


upload_button = driver.find_element(By.ID, 'uploadButton')
upload_button.click()

Aside from the methods in the official documentation,
refresh the page after entering the second website to recapture the current window, increase the waiting time to capture the popup content, and switch back to the main execution window...
So far, none of these methods can capture the new window and alert popup. If I manually interact with the alert during the automation process, only then can I capture the new browser page.

Where's the code you've tried? What errors are you getting? Please read [ask], especially the part about [mcve] (MCVE). Take the code you are using, reduce it to an MCVE, and then post that code as text, properly indented and formatted. Post the full error message as text, properly formatted, and indicate on which line the error is occurring.

Thanks to JeffC's reminder, I have added the Python code again. However, I am still unable to capture the window and alert on the second page. I first tried to capture the new window, but it remained in a waiting state and could not be captured. I also tried to capture the alert first, but it still kept waiting and couldn't capture it.

I'm assuming that because you have an ID that you are using to locate the alert, that it's an HTML dialog as opposed to a JS alert? Have you checked to see if it's in an IFRAME or shadow-root?

Thanks to JeffC' reply . I manually clicked on the alert first to check the structure of the webpage. From the structure, I only saw a JS window.onload alert, and there was no IFRAME or shadow-root design.I also conducted some tests. If I click the open_window_button and then try to capture all windows, or use execute_script to force the opening in a new tab, it causes window_handles to become unresponsive, resulting in a stall.

There are a few different things going on in your example, I'll go over them separately.
Generally Handling Alerts
If you don't care about the alerts and simply want to proceed, you can set a default behavior via unhandledPromptBehavior
options = ChromeOptions()
options.set_capability('unhandledPromptBehavior', 'accept')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options)

Or you can otherwise handle the prompt yourself, as in JavaScript alerts, prompts and confirmations
element = driver.find_element(By.LINK_TEXT, "See an example alert")
element.click()

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, timeout=2)
alert = wait.until(lambda d : d.switch_to.alert)
text = alert.text
alert.accept()

Blocking scripts
By default, Selenium waits until the page is completely loaded before handling control to your script. See pageLoadStrategy. Your second page is using a blocking onload script, so it's never completely loaded until the alert is dismissed. I suggest you use the none strategy instead, which doesn't block the driver at all.
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.page_load_strategy = 'none'
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)

Alerts in new windows
See Switching windows or tabs. Selenium can't detect which window or tab is considered active by the operating system, so you need to switch manually. However, when a new window has an alert, acessing driver.window_handles raises an UnexpectedAlertPresentException. I haven't found a documented way to go around this issue, but the following snippet seems to work for me
try:
    driver.window_handles
except:
    pass
driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[1])

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, timeout=2)
alert = wait.until(lambda d : d.switch_to.alert)
alert.accept()

Complete Example
The following code works for me with selenium==4.21.0.
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait

URL = 'http://127.0.0.1:5500/index.html'

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.page_load_strategy = 'none'
driver = webdriver.Chrome(
    options=options,
    service=Service(),
)
driver.implicitly_wait(5)
driver.get(URL)

open_window_button = driver.find_element(By.ID, 'openWindow')
open_window_button.click()

try:
    driver.window_handles
except:
    pass
driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[1])

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, timeout=2)
alert = wait.until(lambda d : d.switch_to.alert)
alert.accept()

# At this point, the alert is accepted,
# proceed with other logic.
import time
time.sleep(5)


thanks for your reply.
The first method attempts to ignore the alerts directly, but it still remains in a waiting state with no action taken.
The second method also shows no response. After testing, I found that it still needs to capture the elements on the page. However, when I open the developer tools and refresh the page, I see that no elements are present. As a result, trying to capture elements with find_element fails to retrieve anything.

@user25117354, I have updated my answer with a working example and a few extra details.

Boyan Hristov,Thank you very much for your assistance; it has been helpful. Normally, operations and routine configurations employ fully loaded resources before proceeding, but I forgot that I could replace the wait for loading with time.sleep(sec) and also disable the package's own waiting mechanism. You're so creative!
